# How to read the current program counter (PC) in Solidity or Yul?

Tags: solidity, evm, assembly, opcode

I was reading about the [EVM dialect](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/yul.html#evm-dialect) in the docs, and saw this:

| Instruction | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| pc() | Current position in code |

I went to [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org) to try it out:

```
function read_pc() external view returns (uint256 result) {
    assembly {
        result := pc()
    }
}
```

But I was given this error:

> SyntaxError. PC instruction is a low-level EVM feature. Because of that PC is disallowed in strict assembly.

If that doesn't work, is there another way to read the current program counter (PC) in either Solidity or Yul?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to use the `PC` opcode directly in Solidity was removed in Solidity 0.7. However, you may be able to use `PC` again in the future via the [`verbatim` assembly builtin](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/yul.html?highlight=verbatim#verbatim). Currently, you can only use `verbatim` in contracts written in yul. If the Solidity team decides to expose `verbatim` for normal Solidity contracts, it will allow you to inject arbitrary bytecode into your contract to get the `PC` as follows:

```
function read_pc() public view returns (uint256 result) {
  assembly {
    result := verbatim_0i_1o(hex"58")
  }
}
```